# Split data frames into K fold after randomizing in R

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame with 6 rows. I want to split it into 5 folds, so ultimately there would be 4 data frames with 1 element each and the last data frame should have 2 elements. I have tried the following code. But it doesnot help. I am new to R. Any help is appreciated.

```
a = matrix(1:12,6,2)
d <- split(a,rep(1:6,each=4))    
Warning message:
In split.default(a, rep(1:6, each = 4)) :
data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` expects as vector with groups as it's second argument. In your case

```
ngroups <- 5
floor(seq(1, ngroups, length.out = nrow(a)))
```

ans also `split` doesn't work that well with matrices, so first convert to `data.frame`:

```
split(as.data.frame(a), floor(seq(1, ngroups, length.out = nrow(a))))
```

**Edit**: Following a suggestion from @IShouldByABoat, the following also works for `matrix` objects:

```
split.as.data.frame(a, floor(seq(1, ngroups, length.out = nrow(a))))
```

Comment: The help page for `split` suggests that matrices will be handled with `split.data.frame`. (It's generic.)

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat I added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: split(as.data.frame(a), floor(seq(1, ngroups, length.out = nrow(a)))) is working, but I want to have the left over rows in the last fold, I mean in this case the 5th group should have 2 rows.

Comment: @pa1geek use `ceiling` instead of `floor`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the "1 element each" aspect which seems to be problematic with R's version of matrix objects, but here is a way to split into the elements of a 12 element matrix that satify the requirements:

```
split( matrix(1:12,ncol=2), findInterval(1:6, c(sort(sample(1:6,5)),Inf)))
$`1`
[1] 1 7

$`2`
[1] 2 3 8 9

$`3`
[1]  4 10

$`4`
[1]  5 11

$`5`
[1]  6 12
```

If you wanted to fom them back int o two-column matrices:

```
lapply( split( matrix(1:12,ncol=2), findInterval(1:6, c(sort(sample(1:6,5)),Inf))) ,
        matrix, ncol=2)
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    8

$`3`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    9

$`4`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   10
[2,]    5   11

$`5`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   12
```

Comment: The second one works for me, but how can I push the 2 row matrix from $`4` to the last one. ?

Comment: Set it equal to 'my.matrices', then `my.matrices[sapply(my.matrices, length)]`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using the modulo operator on the 1:6 sequence.  For your example, try this:

```
a = matrix(1:12, 6, 2)
d = split(as.data.frame(a), 1:6%%5)
```

Simple, and it gets the job done.

For splitting into K folds, you might find using the following useful:

```
nfolds = 5
a = matrix(1:12, 6, 2)
folds = 1:nrow(a)%%nfolds  # or sample(1:nrow(a)%%nfolds) if you want to randomize
fold = 1  # which ever fold you want to test with
train = a[folds != fold,]
test = a[folds == fold,]
```